# What's the Idea Behind Recursive Least Squares (RLS)? How Could It Be Derived?

Tags: least-squares, recursive-algorithms

The simply explanation of recursive Least squares (RLS) is:

$$\theta(t) = \theta(t-1) -P(t)\phi(t)[y(t) - \theta ^T(t)\theta(t-1)]$$
$$P^{-1}(t) = P^{-1} + \phi(t) \phi^T(t)$$

Where $\phi$ is the regression vector. I understand that this is the error of measurement:

$$y(t) - \theta ^T(t)\theta(t-1)$$

And this is the error of parameter $\theta$

$$P(t)\phi(t)[y(t) - \theta ^T(t)\theta(t-1)]$$

But my question is. Why are $P$ as this:

$$P^{-1}(t) = P^{-1} + \phi(t) \phi^T(t)$$

??

$P(t)$ will be a matrix, but why a matrix? Why not a scalar? What's the idea behind this formula ?

$$P^{-1}(t) = P^{-1}(t-1) + \phi(t) \phi^T(t)$$

Why inverse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recursive least squares tries to identify the parameter $\theta$ which satisfies the following relation

$$
z = \phi^\top\,\theta, \tag{1}
$$

where $z$ and $\phi$ are known. When assuming that $n$ data points are known then equation $(1)$ can be extended to the following equation

$$
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
z_1 \\ z_2 \\ \vdots \\ z_n
\end{bmatrix}
}_{Z_n} = 
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi^\top_1 \\ \phi^\top_2 \\ \vdots \\ \phi^\top_n
\end{bmatrix}
}_{\Phi_n} \theta. \tag{2}
$$

The normal [least squares solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#The_general_problem) for $\theta$ would then be

$$
\hat{\theta}_n = \left(\Phi_n^\top\,\Phi_n\right)^{-1}\,\Phi_n^\top\,Z_n \tag{3}
$$

Using the definition of $Z_n$ and $\Phi_n$ in equation $(2)$ then $Z_{n+1}$ and $\Phi_{n+1}$ can be written as

$$
Z_{n+1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
Z_n \\ z_{n+1}
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
\Phi_{n+1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi_n \\ \phi_{n+1}^\top
\end{bmatrix},
$$

so the least squares solution using $n+1$ points can also be written as

$$
\begin{align}
\hat{\theta}_{n+1} &= \left(\Phi_{n+1}^\top\,\Phi_{n+1}\right)^{-1}\,\Phi_{n+1}^\top\,Z_{n+1}, \\
&= \left(\Phi_n^\top\,\Phi_n + \phi_{n+1}\,\phi_{n+1}^\top\right)^{-1}\,\left(\Phi_n^\top\,Z_n + \phi_{n+1}\,z_{n+1}\right).
\end{align}
\tag{4}
$$

By defining $P_n = \left(\Phi_n^\top\,\Phi_n\right)^{-1}$ then, using the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity), $P_{n+1}$ can be written as

$$
\begin{align}
P_{n+1} &= \left(\Phi_n^\top\,\Phi_n + \phi_{n+1}\,\phi_{n+1}^\top\right)^{-1}, \\
&= P_n - P_n\,\phi_{n+1}\,\left(1 + \phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n\,\phi_{n+1}\right)^{-1}\,\phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n,
\end{align}
$$

since $1 + \phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n\,\phi_{n+1}$ is scalar it can also be written as

$$
P_{n+1} = P_n - \frac{P_n\,\phi_{n+1}\,\phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n}{1 + \phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n\,\phi_{n+1}} = \left(I - \frac{P_n\,\phi_{n+1}\,\phi_{n+1}^\top}{1 + \phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n\,\phi_{n+1}}\right) P_n. \tag{5}
$$

Substituting equation $(5)$ into equation $(4)$ gives

$$
\hat{\theta}_{n+1} = \left(I - \frac{P_n\,\phi_{n+1}\,\phi_{n+1}^\top}{1 + \phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n\,\phi_{n+1}}\right) P_n\,\left(\Phi_n^\top\,Z_n + \phi_{n+1}\,z_{n+1}\right).
$$

By substituting $P_n$ into equation $(3)$ then it can be shown that $\hat{\theta}_n = P_n\,\Phi^\top_n\,Z_n$, so the above equation can also be written as

$$
\hat{\theta}_{n+1} = \left(I - \frac{P_n\,\phi_{n+1}\,\phi_{n+1}^\top}{1 + \phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n\,\phi_{n+1}}\right) \left(\hat{\theta}_n + P_n\,\phi_{n+1}\,z_{n+1}\right),
$$

which does no longer contain $Z_n$ or $\Phi_n$, which makes it recursive. Expanding the brackets of the above equation and simplifying the resulting equation gives

$$
\begin{align}
\hat{\theta}_{n+1} &= \hat{\theta}_n + P_n\,\phi_{n+1}\,z_{n+1} - \frac{P_n\,\phi_{n+1}\,\phi_{n+1}^\top \left(\hat{\theta}_n + P_n\,\phi_{n+1}\,z_{n+1}\right)}{1 + \phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n\,\phi_{n+1}}, \\
&= \hat{\theta}_n + P_n\,\phi_{n+1}\left(z_{n+1} - \frac{\phi_{n+1}^\top \hat{\theta}_n}{1 + \phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n\,\phi_{n+1}} - \frac{\phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n\,\phi_{n+1}}{1 + \phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n\,\phi_{n+1}}\,z_{n+1}\right), \\
&= \hat{\theta}_n + P_n\,\phi_{n+1}\left(\frac{z_{n+1}}{1 + \phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n\,\phi_{n+1}} - \frac{\phi_{n+1}^\top \hat{\theta}_n}{1 + \phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n\,\phi_{n+1}}\right), \\
&= \hat{\theta}_n + \frac{P_n\,\phi_{n+1}}{1 + \phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n\,\phi_{n+1}} \left(z_{n+1} - \phi_{n+1}^\top\,\hat{\theta}_n\right). \\
\end{align}
$$

There are common terms in both $P_{n+1}$ and $\hat{\theta}_{n+1}$, so in order to avoid calculating the same thing twice one often defines the update law as

$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
K_n &= \frac{P_n\,\phi_{n+1}}{1 + \phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n\,\phi_{n+1}} \\
P_{n+1} &= P_n - K_n\,\phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n \\
\hat{\theta}_{n+1} &= \hat{\theta}_n + K_n \left(z_{n+1} - \phi_{n+1}^\top\,\hat{\theta}_n\right)
\end{align}
\right. \tag{6}
$$

---

Often however a forgetting factor is used as well, which weighs "old data" less and less the "older" it gets. Basically the solution to the least squares in equation $(3)$ is turned into a weighted least squares with exponentially decaying weights. One way of writing this is by changing equation $(2)$ into

$$
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha^{n-1}\,z_1 \\ \alpha^{n-2}\,z_2 \\ \vdots \\ z_n
\end{bmatrix}
}_{Z_n} = 
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha^{n-1}\,\phi^\top_1 \\ \alpha^{n-2}\,\phi^\top_2 \\ \vdots \\ \phi^\top_n
\end{bmatrix}
}_{\Phi_n} \theta, \tag{7}
$$

where it can be noted that $0<\alpha\leq1$. An equivalent solution would be to use a diagonal weighting matrix with $\begin{bmatrix}\alpha^{n-1} & \alpha^{n-2} & \cdots & 1\end{bmatrix}$ on its diagonal. By now using the definition of $Z_n$ and $\Phi_n$ in equation $(7)$ then $Z_{n+1}$ and $\Phi_{n+1}$ can be written as

$$
Z_{n+1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha\,Z_n \\ z_{n+1}
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
\Phi_{n+1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha\,\Phi_n \\ \phi_{n+1}^\top
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The end result of equation $(4)$ now becomes

$$
\hat{\theta}_{n+1} = \left(\alpha^2\,\Phi_n^\top\,\Phi_n + \phi_{n+1}\,\phi_{n+1}^\top\right)^{-1}\,\left(\alpha^2\,\Phi_n^\top\,Z_n + \phi_{n+1}\,z_{n+1}\right). \tag{8}
$$

Similarly equation $(5)$ becomes

$$
P_{n+1} = \alpha^{-2}\,\left(P_n - \frac{P_n\,\phi_{n+1}\,\phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n}{\alpha^2 + \phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n\,\phi_{n+1}}\right) = \alpha^{-2}\,\left(I - \frac{P_n\,\phi_{n+1}\,\phi_{n+1}^\top}{\alpha^2 + \phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n\,\phi_{n+1}}\right)\,P_n. \tag{9}
$$

By substituting equation $(9)$ into equation $(8)$ and expanding and simplifying it yields

$$
\hat{\theta}_{n+1} = \hat{\theta}_n + \frac{P_n\,\phi_{n+1}}{\alpha^2 + \phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n\,\phi_{n+1}}\,\left(z_{n+1} - \phi_{n+1}^\top\,\hat{\theta}_n\right). \tag{10}
$$

Since the weight factor $\alpha$ only appears squared one often defines the forgetting factor parameter as $\lambda = \alpha^2$. By again factoring out the common term then the following update law can be obtained

$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
K_n &= \frac{P_n\,\phi_{n+1}}{\lambda + \phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n\,\phi_{n+1}} \\
P_{n+1} &= \lambda^{-1} \left(P_n - K_n\,\phi_{n+1}^\top\,P_n\right) \\
\hat{\theta}_{n+1} &= \hat{\theta}_n + K_n \left(z_{n+1} - \phi_{n+1}^\top\,\hat{\theta}_n\right)
\end{align}
\right. \tag{11}
$$

Comment: Wow! To much! I accept this answer because you have right, but still...I don't understand the answer.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson What do you not understand? You are familiar with the normal least squares solution?

Comment: No, I just asking why does $P$ will be described as: $$P^{-1}(t) = P^{-1}(t-1) + \phi(t) \phi^T(t)$$ What's the idea behind to create a matrix of the the regresson vector $\phi(t) \phi^T(t)$ ? Why inverse?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson That is basically the matrix inside the inverse of equation $(4)$.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Namely: 
$$
\Phi_{n+1}^\top\,\Phi_{n+1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi_n^\top & \phi_{n+1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi_n \\ \phi_{n+1}^\top
\end{bmatrix}
= \Phi_n^\top\,\Phi_n + \phi_{n+1}\,\phi_{n+1}^\top
$$

Comment: Yes. But why ? ?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson By adding one more data point ($z_{n+1}$ and $\phi_{n+1}^\top$) to equation $(2)$, then by using the definition for $Z_n$ and $\Phi_n$ from equation $(2)$ you get
$$
Z_{n+1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
Z_n \\ z_{n+1}
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
\Phi_{n+1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi_n \\ \phi_{n+1}^\top
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now using that I defined $P_n^{-1}$ as $\Phi_n^\top\,\Phi_n$ and thus $P_{n+1}^{-1}$ would be $\Phi_{n+1}^\top\,\Phi_{n+1}$, then the equation in my previous comment tells us that $P_{n+1}^{-1}=P_n^{-1}+ \phi_{n+1}\,\phi_{n+1}^\top$.

Comment: @shaikmoeed It should be scalar. Namely, $\alpha$ is scalar, $P_n$ is a square $n \times n$ matrix and $\phi_{n+1}$ is a vector of length $n$. Maybe you are used to the convention that a vectors are row vectors, but I use the convention that vectors are column vectors.

Comment: @shaikmoeed if you mean $P_n$ then yes. For the complete iteration you could use $(6)$ (or $(11)$ if you want to use exponential forgetting, though for $\lambda=1$ they are identical).